# Confused by Factory Girl - Testing edit of an associated model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber, factory-bot

I have the following models:

```
Student has_many Lesson
Lesson belongs_to Student
```

And I want to test that a Student can edit a Lesson.

Here is what I have started doing:

```
 Given I am logged in as a student
```

Which step definition sets a @student object from a Factory (see above) and signs the student in.

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :student do
    first_name 'student'
    last_name 'last name student'
  end
end
```

At this point is where I get stuck.  I know I can create a Factory for a Lesson, something like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :lesson do
    name 'maths'
    level 'high school'
  end
end
```

But I would like to relate that lesson to the professor that is signed in.  So my question is... How would I go to the next step:

1. Create a lesson associated to the signed in student
2. Edit lesson (I need to know the id to visit the lesson/:id page)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you already have `belongs_to :lecturer` in your Lesson model and `has_many :lessons` in your Lecturer model.

Firstly I would define your Lesson factory as follows (assuming you already have a Lecturer factory):

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :lesson do
    name 'maths'
    level 'high school'
    association :lecturer
  end
end
```

The `association :lecturer` line will create a Lecturer using the factory and assign in to the Lesson.

In your test, you can do something as follows, in order to assign your signed in Lecturer to the Lessons you create:

```
FactoryGirl.create(:lesson, lecturer: signed_in_lecturer)
```

Hope this helps.

PS: I don't use cucumber, so you might need to tweak the code slightly to take it into account.